# JavaScript function to replace HTML contents for a few seconds, then revert back.

Tags: javascript, html, hide, settimeout, setinterval

I'm making a hangman game using JavaScript and need to hide some HTML for a few seconds to display an error message, and then revert back to the original HTML. I've tried using setTimeout(); and setInterval(); but those seem to just wait a few seconds before displaying the error message.

Here's the code for reference:

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <div id="alredGuess" class="col">
        <div>
            <span id="guessedLetters"></span> <br>
        </div>
        <div>Guesses left:<span id="guessesLeft">10</span></div>
        <div>Wins:<span id="wins">0</span></div>
        <div>Losses:<span id="losses">0</span></div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
if (gameRunning === true && guessedLetterBank.indexOf(letter) === -1) {
        // run game logic
        guessedLetterBank.push(letter);

        // Check if letter is in picked word
        for (var i = 0; i < pickedWord.length; i++) {
            //convert to lower case
            if (pickedWord[i].toLowerCase() === letter.toLowerCase()) {
                //if match, swap placeholder
                pickedWordPlaceholderArr[i] = pickedWord[i];
            }
        }

        $placeholders.textContent = pickedWordPlaceholderArr.join("");
        checkIncorrect(letter);

    } else if (gameRunning === false) {
        $placeholders.textContent = "Press \"A\" To Begin!"
    } else {
        //alert("You've already guessed this letter.")
        function newAlert() {
            var hideDiv = document.getElementById("alredGuess");
            if (hideDiv.style.display = "block") {
                hideDiv.style.display = "none";
              }
            }
            hideDiv.textContent("You've already guessed this letter!");
            function showDiv() {
            var showDiv = document.getElementById("alredGuess");
            if (hideDiv.style.display = "none") {
                hideDiv.style.display = "block";
              }
             }
            }
           }
            setInterval(newAlert, 3000);
    }
```

Comment: You can display the message, then using `setTimeout` hide it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tip 1**

Well, first of all i don't recommend using `display: block|none` to show or hide DOM elements. Instead try using `visibility: visible|hidden` or better, toggle a css class name such as : `.hidden`. That's because when you set a DOM element's display to none, its width and height are gonna be set to zero, often causing an unwanted loss of space because the DOM node visually collapses. With the visibility property, for example, the element just disappears without loss of space.

**Tip 2**

Error/status messages should always live within their own containers. Do not display messages in substitution of some content you need to revert back after.
It is always better to prepare an empty `<div>`, hide it by default with a generic `.hidden`CSS class and then remove this one as soon as you need to display the container.

**Suggested solution**

Now, in your case, i think you're using `setInterval`in the wrong way. You have to immediately show the alert message, then make it disappear after a few seconds.
As suggested above, this should be done by toggling CSS classes, using different containers and using `setTimeout` in order to remove/add the CSS classes as soon as the interval is over.  Basically, the `setTimeout` restores everything to its original state.

So, given this HTML code:

```
<div id="alredGuess">This is the original text</div>
<div id="alertbox" class="hidden"></div>
```

and this CSS code:

```
.hidden { visibility: hidden; }
```

try this:

```
var alertTimeout = 1000; // Timeout in milliseconds.

function showAlertMessage() {

    // This is your original text container.
    var alredGuess = document.getElementById("alredGuess");

    // This is the new error message container named #alertbox
    var alertBox = document.getElementById("alertbox");

    // Now let's fill it with the specific error text (better using HTML here).
    alertBox.innerHTML = "You've already guessed this letter!";

    // Hide the original container by adding an .hidden css class.
    alredGuess.classList.add('hidden');

    // Show the error message container by removing its default .hidden css class.
    alertBox.classList.remove('hidden');

   // Then set up an interval: as it ends, revert everything to its original state.
    setTimeout(function() {
        alertBox.classList.add('hidden');
        alredGuess.classList.remove('hidden');
    }, alertTimeout);
}

// Call the function.
showAlertMessage();
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qyk4jspd/

Hope this helps.